# Ruby/Rails: pass arguments to command line application from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdftk

How do you pass arguments from within a rake task and execute a command-line application from Ruby/Rails?

Specifically I'm trying to use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) (I can't find a comparable gem) to split some PDFs into individual pages. Args I'd like to pass are within `< >` below:

```
$ pdftk <filename.pdf> burst output <filename_%04d.pdf>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ruby code for your rake task:

```
`pdftk #{input_filename} burst output #{output_filename}`
```

You could also do:

```
system("pdftk #{input_filename} burst output #{output_filename}")
```

`system()` just returns true or false.  backticks or `%x()` returns whatever output the system call generates.  Usually backticks are preferred, but if you don't care, then you could use `system()`.  I always use backticks because it's more concise.

More info here: http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands

Comment: that simple huh? thought maybe i'd have to call some library to execute a command... guess not! thanks!

Comment: That simple.  You can get some more info here: http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands

Comment: As an aside, I use ruby for many shell scripts because of this.  I f***ing hate bash.

Comment: no, it's a system call, ruby `require` wouldn't help.  If it's not working, make sure the environment variables are set such that pdftk can be called from wherever you're invoking the rake task

Comment: Also updated my answer w/info about `system()` if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

e.g. as:

```
filename = 'filename.pdf'
filename_out = 'filename_%04d.pdf'

`pdftk #{filename} burst output #{filename_out}`
```

or

```
system("pdftk #{filename} burst output #{filename_out}")
```

`system` returns a retrun code, the backtick-version return STDOUT.

If you need stdout and stderr, you may also use `Open3.open3`:

```
filename = 'filename.pdf'
filename_out = 'filename_%04d.pdf'
cmd = "pdftk #{filename} burst output #{filename_out}"

require 'open3'
Open3.popen3(cmd){ |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  puts "This is STDOUT of #{cmd}:"
  puts stdout.read
  puts "This is STDERR of #{cmd}:"
  puts stderr.read
}
```

Comment: what's that `system` function doing? that's kind of what I was expecting to have to do... pros/cons to one style over the other?

Comment: system() returns true or false.  backticks or `%x()` returns whatever output the system call generates.  Usually backticks are preferred, but if you don't care, then you could use `system()`.  I always use backticks because it's more concise.

Comment: I adapted my answer and added a solution with `Open3.popen3` to get stderr and stdout.